# asterisk entry point to a SIP dialplan

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk, asteriskami

I understand this should be really easy but I can't find my way around the asterisk configuration files to do this.

What I need in an `entry point` for a `external SIP call` to execute an asterisk script. To keep things simple let's say I want to execute something like this:

```
[my888app]
exten => 888,1,Answer()
exten => 888,2,SayDigits(1234)
exten => 888,3,Hangup
```

The user will dial this particular 888 SIP extension in the form:

```
sip:888@mydomain.com
```

This is not an `internal` call, the call comes from another server, to test I'm using this [Phono sample](http://s.phono.com/releases/0.4/samples/kitchen-sink/www/index.html) and the call is getting onto the asterisk server ok, the problem is that I have no idea how to route it to `my888app`. Already tried `/etc/asterisk/sip_general_custom.conf` without luck, guess the problem is the context [my888app] is not right. I already have the asterisk CLI in front of me

So, to recap:

- No DID funny business, just SIP
- In which `.conf` file do I put the `[my888appp]`
- I dont understand if 888 is an `entension` or a `channel`
- Multiple calls will be made at the same time to [my888app], is that a
  problem?
- Right now when I dial from the Phono app I get `please enter the
  channel number follow by the # sign`, I dont know if that is helpful
  or not

Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to tell Asterisk the default context (my888app in this case) for sip trunk in your sip*.conf. put a line `context=my888app` under [general] or your friend/peer config in sip*.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need check the context attributes in your sip.conf. You can have a context in general section and you can have another in your peer definition, if you dont define any specific context in you peer then the general context attribute is assumed.

For simplicity I advice you change context in general section of sip.conf and put your my888app in extensions.conf.

Example of sip.conf general section:

```
[general]
context=my888app
...
```

About 888: it is a extension, an extension is a end point to your call. A channel is a  object created dynamically when setting up a call to retain the session information and to exchange data (voice) between two points.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a lot of searching turns out the routing is as follows (default FreePBX installation):

- The SIP calls goes into a context called `from-sip-external`
- from there, it goes to the context `from-trunk`
- from there it goes to `from-pstn`
- from there it goes to `ext-did-catchall`

And there, in `ext-did-catchall`, is where I can put `my888app` and it will execute ok

I'm 100% positive this is not the correct place to put the app, but as I'm not an Asterisk expert I will settle for it.

Hope this help someone else.
Thanks.-

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple, Any external call first land on the context which is defined under  general section in sip.conf file. There you can define your own dial plan. if you want to redirect to your own context from there then you can use GoSub.